# How to get Elements values inside element with class

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

Below code is created from my DB so its multiple with same `classes` name but with different contents.
What i need to do is that when button with `class = 'config'` is clicked i need to get the values `['value','type','info']` of `this` div  with `this` class = `config`  .
How would i go ahead with this ?

```
$(".config").click(function(){
     var id = $(this).attr('id');
});
```

Any Hint ??

**HTML**

```
<div class="mws-form-row bordered">
   <label class="mws-form-label"><?php echo SaleAdmin_Engine::getConfigName($this->result[0]['config_name']) ; ?></label>
      <div class="mws-form-item">
         <b>Value</b> <input type="text" class="value required large" value="<?php echo $this->result[0]['config_value']; ?>">
         <b>Type</b> <input type="text" class="type required  large" value="<?php echo $this->result[0]['config_type']; ?>">
         <b>Info</b>  <textarea rows="" cols="" class="info required  large"><?php echo $this->result[0]['config_info']; ?></textarea>
      </div>
<button class="config btn btn-inverse btn-small" rel="<?php echo $this->result[0]['config_id']; ?>" type="button">Save</button>
</div>
```

Comment: You are saying what you want to do but you're not telling where is the problem in the code is persisting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly something like this should work for you

```
   $(".config").click(function(){
        var form1 = $(this).parent();           
        var value = form1.find(".value").value();
        var type = form1.find(".type").value();
        var info = form1.find(".info").value();
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

The `this` in your selector is referencing the button which does not have the elements you are looking for.  In order to get those elements you need to get the parent form that the button is related to.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".config").click(function(){
        var form1 = $(this).parent();           
        var value = form1.find(".value").val();
        var type = form1.find(".type").val();
        var info = form1.find(".info").val();  
    });   
});
```

Here is a working [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x8KSR/).

Answer (score 0):

You can get a collection using the jQuery class selector and then iterate over them all in one shot using jQuery map function to build your values.

```
$(".config").click(function(){
  //Get all items with required class
  var resultArray = $.map($(".required"), function(val){
    return val.value;
  });
  console.log(resultArray);
});
```

See it in action in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3KNJs/)